# Terraform plan shows IAM policy is removing

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Policy and role already exist but terraform plan shows policy will be updated in-place. if I apply I think it will remove the existing policy as per plan, where has no change in code. I see policy document is reading the same way its removing.

my aws provider version 4.29

code in my module for policy

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "task_execution_role_with_cloudwatch_policy_doc" {

  count = var.container_log_driver == "awslogs" ? 1 : 0

  statement {
    actions = [
      "logs:CreateLogStream",
      "logs:PutLogEvents",
    ]

    resources = [
      "${aws_cloudwatch_log_group.main[0].arn}:*"
    ]

  }

  statement {
    actions = [
      "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
    ]

    resources = [
      "*"
    ]
  }

  statement {
    actions = [
      "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
      "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
      "ecr:BatchGetImage",
    ]

    resources = var.ecr_repo_arns
  }

  statement {
    actions = [
      "ssm:Describe*",
      "ssm:Get*",
      "ssm:List*",
    ]

    resources = [
      "arn:aws:ssm:*:*:parameter/${local.ssm_name_env}/*",
      "arn:aws:ssm:*:*:parameter/xxxxx/*",
      "arn:aws:ssm:*:*:parameter/${var.env}/xxxxx/*",
      "arn:aws:ssm:*:*:parameter/xxxx/*",
      "arn:aws:ssm:*:*:parameter/xxxxxx/*",
      "arn:aws:ssm:*:*:parameter/xxxxx/*"
    ]
  }
}
```

Below is the plan output

```
# aws_iam_role_policy.task_execution_role_policy[0] will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "task_execution_role_policy" {
        id     = "ecs-task-execution-role-xxxxxxx:ecs-task-execution-role-xxxxxxxxx-policy"
        name   = "ecs-task-execution-role-xxxxxxxxxxx-policy"
      ~ policy = jsonencode(
            {
              - Statement = [
                  - {
                      - Action   = [
                          - "logs:PutLogEvents",
                          - "logs:CreateLogStream",
                        ]
                      - Effect   = "Allow"
                      - Resource = "arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:123456789:log-group:/ecs/xxxxxxxxxx:*"
                      - Sid      = ""
                    },
                  - {
                      - Action   = "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken"
                      - Effect   = "Allow"
                      - Resource = "*"
                      - Sid      = ""
                    },
                  - {
                      - Action   = [
                          - "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                          - "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                          - "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                        ]
                      - Effect   = "Allow"
                      - Resource = "*"
                      - Sid      = ""
                    },
                  - {
                      - Action   = [
                          - "ssm:List*",
                          - "ssm:Get*",
                          - "ssm:Describe*",
                        ]
                      - Effect   = "Allow"
                      - Resource = [
                          - "arn:aws:ssm:*:*:parameter/dev/aurora/*",
                          - "arn:aws:ssm:*:*:parameter/test-service/*",
                          - "arn:aws:ssm:*:*:parameter/ecs/*",
                          - "arn:aws:ssm:*:*:parameter/aurora/*",
                          - "arn:aws:ssm:*:*:parameter/test-service/*",
                        ]
                      - Sid      = ""
                    },
                ]
              - Version   = "2012-10-17"
            }
        ) -> (known after apply)
        # (1 unchanged attribute hidden)
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure the policy gets deleted/removed? Does the `container_log_driver` value move from `true` to `false` at any point?

Comment: Also we would need to see the relevant plan output to assist.

Comment: Have a look at the contents of the terraform state and see if the policy in question is being tracked?

Comment: @MattSchuchard I have added plan output

Comment: @MaruthiraoKonda what is the value of `container_log_driver` when you are observing this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

In your terraform code you have:

```
  statement {
    actions = [
      "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
      "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
      "ecr:BatchGetImage",
    ]

    resources = var.ecr_repo_arns
  }
```

But in the plan output, we see:

```
                  - {
                      - Action   = [
                          - "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                          - "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                          - "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                        ]
                      - Effect   = "Allow"
                      - Resource = "*"
                      - Sid      = ""
                    },
```

So I'm guessing this is changing to an actual list. The reason you see `known after apply` is because those are calculated values. Unless, you are passing in `*` as the variable `ecr_repo_arns`.

But it isn't removing your policy. `~` means updating, so it is updating from the statements there to statements `(known after apply)`, which is probably only slightly different. Maybe even the order of a list, if your variable is a list that doesn't have a stable order.

Comment: we are passing variable *.   variable "ecr_repo_arns" {
  description = "The ARNs of the ECR repos.  By default, allows all repositories."
  type        = list(string)
  default     = [
    "*"
  ]
}

Comment: What is the value you're passing? Seems the state represents it having been passed as `*` which would not satisfy `type = list(string)`. It may be that you passed `["*"]` and IAM has modified this to just `"*"`, but I think the provider deals with this.

Comment: variable "ecr_repo_arns" {
  description = "The ARNs of the ECR repos.  By default, allows all repositories."
  type        = list(string)
  default     = [    " * "   ]
}
yes passing " * ".